# Messaging system MYSQL, issue with getting latest reply

Tags: mysql

I have a table with

message_id, to_id, from_id, message

I made a threaded messaging system. I have 5 people talking to 1 member.

As the member I see

Member 1 says hi, member 2 says hello    ( I want this to say latest reply was hello )

Member 1 says hi, member 3 says hi, member 1 says welcome ( I want this to say welcome )

member 2 says hi (I want this to say hi )

Now, I'm only provided with one of the ID's which is the sessionid of the member1. How would I go about showing scenario 2 where I (member1) have left the latest reply.

I can easily do

```
 SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_id=$session_id ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

but that would only show the INCOMING messages. I need to show the LAST of the incoming AND outgoing messages.

What query would you suggest? :\ Maybe an alteration to the table if there's no efficient way? First time i've ever setup a messaging system, advice is welcome.

Comment: I think you need `thread_id` field. Since there are probably multiple threads where people can chat, otherwise you would ommit where part and just show the latest row from `messages` table.

Comment: Agreed, and should this thread_id field be denormalized? Meaning keep it in a separate table and just combine when needed? or is there no need for that.

Comment: Well that depends. If you're going to have a thread title or some other info specific to thread, you could put it in a separate table. Otherwise, keeping only thread id in a separate table would be overhead since you can group and sort by `thread_id` in the `message` table.

Comment: Just to clarify, since my answer apparently got downvoted, you're after the single most recent message that was either sent or received by the user, right? Or do you want the most recent message sent and the most recent message received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM messages 
WHERE to_id = $session_id
OR from_id = $session_id
ORDER BY message_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `UNION` operator to retrieve the latest incoming message, and tack onto that result the latest outgoing message:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_id=$session_id ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_id=$session_id ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1
```